# in asp.net loading a web user control from within another web user control using Page.LoadControl(path)

Tags: webforms, controls, ascx, webusercontrol, loadcontrol

I have an asp.net page that have a Web User Control  WUC-1 (dynamically added), WUC1 is supposed to load another Web User Control WUC-2.

To accomplish this I am using Page.LoadControl(~/path to control) method. This method suddenly started to error as below

[30-08-2020 03:10:46 PM] [ManagementImagesControl.ascx.cs] [mangtListView_ItemCommand] [a87e9f1b-826c-4379-b646-ac85e80f4031]
[Message] **

> c:\Users\path\Projects\project folder\other folder\WUC-2.ascx(60):
> error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'bool'

**

[StackTrace]    at
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
at
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath)
at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(String virtualPath)
at
projectname.Controls.ManagementImagesControl.mangtListView_ItemCommand(Object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e) in c:\Users\project folder\other folder\WUC1.ascx.cs:line 273

[Source] System.Web

[InnerException]

line 273 is exactly from where the above log is generated;

**`UserControl ucGal = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/path/WUC-2.ascx");`**

I would appreciate if anyone can shed some light on it. It was working perfectly fine from YEARS until now

Comment: hard to understand why bool to string is being generated in it. Is it some bug in asp.net?

Comment: I have found the solution.

 - First of all I commented most of the scripting in .ascx file
 - Uncommented scripting line by line in the form of debuging
 - Found that I had recently concatenated a string with a boolean control of listview that was databind 

> Checked='<%# "Active/Deactive" + Eval("itemactive") %>'

 - Removed the string 

> Checked='<%# Eval("itemactive") %>'

-It started to work as a charm